# Why is my "Component Services" window so slow?

Tags: configuration, com+

I have a newly configured Windows Server 2003 VM.

One of the issues with the old VM was that whenever I open up "Component Services" from "Administrative Tools", the performance is very bad.  It takes several minutes to create new COM+ applications and add components where it used to take only a few seconds.

I have many components to install and multiple VMs to do this on.  Why would it be so slow and what can I do to make it faster?

It used to run just fine.  I wonder if it could have something to do with the anti-virus software in the office...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in my particular case.  My machine is on Domain X and my user account is on Domain Y.

The solution was to log in as a user on Domain X, the same domain as the machine.  This made the Component Services window respond almost instantaneously.  I'm not entirely sure why this is, though.